# solucion sql server no permite cambios en las tablas

Tags: sql-server

Me sale este mensaje de error al guardar cuando edito el tipo de dato en sql server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución esta en la configuración de MSSQL:

- Ir a tool/options/designer
- Deshabilitar "Prevent saving changes that req..."
- Pulsar en Ok

Y ya no sale el mensaje de error.